# Avoid/automate compiling e1000e driver with new kernel updates

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, intel, nic

I have home server that has installed an ASRock H670 ITX that has NIC Intel I219V, running Ubuntu 20.04.3.

The problem is that kernel does not have driver for this NIC. I had to install manually using e1000e v3.8.7 driver. The problem is that, I only have Network/SSH access to the machine. So If I update the Kernel using apt get ..., next reboot I will lose access, I need to connect Monitor, keyboard etc... to compile and install driver again.

Any ideas how to automate this, or compile the driver for other kernels installed other than the currently running, so next reboot the new kernel will also have the driver loaded?

Comment: Have you tried to use DKMS-based driver from https://github.com/koljah-de/e1000e-dkms-debian ?

Comment: The driver e1000e has been included in recent Ubuntu versions for many years. Check: `modinfo e1000e` Please further clarify your issue.

Comment: In Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04.3 does not detect my Onboard NIC I219V. I had to install it manually.

Comment: @N0rbert your solution seems to work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use DKMS-based driver from https://github.com/koljah-de/e1000e-dkms-debian .